# How to properly redirect HTTPS to local HTTP connected via WireGuard tunnel when the app itself is not using SSL?

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, https, wireguard

I have an domain that is setup with an SSL certificate via Let's Encrypt so it only works via `https://example.com/`

This domain is connected via WireGuard tunnel to my home PC which serves a Laravel app via local IP `192.168.10.10` without SSL so while developing I simply go to `http://192.168.10.10` without certificate.

The domain is working on an Ubuntu VM on EC2 instance and uses nginx to proxy_pass requests from the domain to the local PC which also serves the app via nginx

Everything works well when I use my app locally via the local IP. But when I go to my domain at `https://example.com/` some things don't work. For example login - when I go to `https://example.com/login` and try to login, it first prompts me the `The information you’re about to submit is not secure` page because locally my app is not using HTTPS. Then when I click `Send Anyway` it simply refreshes the login page instead of logging in.

The browser prompts the `The information you’re about to submit is not secure` because when I develop locally, the app generates non-secured URLs, so the form looks like this:

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://example.com/login">
```

So when I change it to secured URL:

```
 <form method="POST" action="https://example.com/login">
```

It works from the domain! But then I get `419 | Page Expired` from my local login page

In the EC2 instance I use nginx simply as proxy to redirect everything from http to https and from the URL to the WireGuard IP.

And in the local PC the app is also served with nginx on port 80